# Cannot login to CockroachDB secure cluster

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cockroachdb

I have a Cockroach cluster set up using official CockroachDB Helm. Cluster is secured with self signed certificates. However, when trying to login using "secure client" provided by docs `cockroach sql --certs-dir /cockroach/cockroach-certs` I'm getting error:

```
[root@cockroachdb-client-secure cockroach]# cockroach sql --certs-dir /cockroach-certs/ --user root --host cockroach-cockroachdb-public
#
# Welcome to the CockroachDB SQL shell.
# All statements must be terminated by a semicolon.
# To exit, type: \q.
#
ERROR: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Failed running "sql"
[root@cockroachdb-client-secure cockroach]#
```

Whats wrong?

Alternatively, when I try to login from cockroach node 0, I'm asked about password, but I don't know what is a root password:

```
[root@cockroach-cockroachdb-0 cockroach]# cockroach sql --certs-dir cockroach-certs/
#
# Welcome to the CockroachDB SQL shell.
# All statements must be terminated by a semicolon.
# To exit, type: \q.
#
Enter password:
```

How can I access this cluster?

Comment: Please paste the full steps you ran and their outputs. Specifically, make sure the cockroach operator is running properly. The [steps](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes.html) are quite involved and you need to read the notes carefully. You also are mentioning both `/cockroach/cockroach-certs` and `/cockroach-certs`. Finally: `root` does not have a password by default, if no client certificate is found, authentication defaults to password but it clearly won't work without a password set.